Spring | Problem with saving to PostgreSQL
I'm newbie Java-dev and I'm trying to make an JavaFX-application that uses Spring.
I have some problems with saving to PostgreSQL.
So, I have a registration form, I'm taking user data and trying to save it to PostgreSQL with Spring Data JPA.
I have hierarchy: com.raddan.Chat > Authorize > Controller(AuthController, RegController), Model(User), Repository(UserRepository), Service(UserDetailsImpl)
So what exactly is here: I press on Registration button and I have an error: userRepository is null.
I'll be thankful if smone can help me with that.

import com.raddan.Chat.Authorize.Model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
@Component
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}



import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

}


import com.raddan.Chat.Authorize.Model.User;
import com.raddan.Chat.Authorize.Repository.UserRepository;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class RegController {

    @FXML
    private Button backToAuthButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField emailField;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane emailPane;

    @FXML
    private Button nextButton1;

    @FXML
    private Button nextButton2;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane passwordPane;

    @FXML
    private Button regButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane usernamePane;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @FXML
    private void handleNextButton1() {
        email = emailField.getText();
        emailPane.setVisible(false);
        usernamePane.setVisible(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleNextButton2() {
        username = usernameField.getText();
        usernamePane.setVisible(false);
        passwordPane.setVisible(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRegButton() {
        password = passwordField.getText();
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);

        userRepository.save(user);
        emailField.clear();
        usernameField.clear();
        passwordField.clear();

        showConfirmationDialog();
    }

    private void showConfirmationDialog() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Success!");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("You successfully registered!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}```


Forget to share application.properties:
spring.application.name=Chat
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=7654
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

If you have more relevant details, post them as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

A JavaFX Controller is not a Spring Controller.  You should not use the @Controller annotation as you have.  See Creating new Instance of @Component each time FXMLLoader calls applicationContext.getBean(class).  A JavaFX controller is not a SpringBootApplication, it should not have that annotation.  You may have other errors.

Basic Spring/JavaFX integration.
